# InDesign CC FindChangeByList How do you remove a style?

Tags: indesign-scripting

This should be really simple and is probably some documentation I can't find.

I need to remove a Character style from a query.

I've tried the following that do not work:

{CharacterStyle.remove}
{appliedCharacterStyle:""}
{appliedCharacterStyle:"[None]"}

What should it be?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This works in my FindChangeByList.txt file perfectly:

appliedCharacterStyle:app.characterStyles[0]

I found the answer here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1432178

Although it is listed as "Unanswered"

Comment: 'Although it is listed as "Unanswered"' — ↑ Same here :)